# NodeJS spam GET - REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I'm new to this API, node fun stuff.

I just setup my node application for a school project and hooked it to a domain. Already it's showing some weird spam GET commands, should I be worried? Is it the server that is getting redirected to those spam sites?

Image to explain:
https://i.gyazo.com/a21b0acf9e3749f7ebabb2d1e6fed4d6.png
- Do not enter the link from the console.

Answer (score 1):

Are these logs being created by your server code? I'm assuming they are, in which case, it is showing the requests being made to the server, the request method (GET,POST,PUT,etc.), and response codes per request that were sent from your server back to the requester.

I'm also assuming these logs are coming from your server code thats deployed on a machine and hooked up to your domain name, in which case, it means that requests were made at

```
{your_domain_name}/assets/title.png (http status code - 200)
{your_domain_name}/status (http status code - 200)
{your_domain_name}/w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind: (http status code - 200)
```

`/assets/title.png`, `/status`, `/w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:` are all called paths and are the destination at which a requester would communicate with your server. Your server code should expose "endpoints" that requesters can interact with - often a SOAP or REST API.

If I've made too many assumptions or you have more questions I'll be happy to adjust or add input.